# Find connecting application to oracle database using session ID

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to determine the application that is using a specific session ID in an Oracle 11g database. I can find the service name of the session id using this query

```
select SID, SERVICE_NAME
from v$session
where SID = <sessionID here>;
```

Unfortunately, several applications use this service name to connect to the database.  Is there another table/query that I can use to determine which application is using this session ID?

Answer (score 1):

There are other columns in [`V$SESSION`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/V-SESSION.html) that *might* be useful, e.g.:

```
select username, osuser, logon_time, status, program, module, client_identifier, client_info
from gv$session
where sid = <sessionID here>;
```

However it is up to your application to set or override the last four values.

For example, a session started from SQL*Plus shows program as something like `sqlplus@client_host (TNS V1-V3)` and module as `SQL*Plus`. SQL Developer shows both values as that name. A JDBC connection will have something like 'JDBC Thin Client' for both by default, but the application can override those and/or set `client_identifier` and `client_info` if it chooses to. As can a Pro*C application, which defaults to both program and module looking something like `exe_name@client_host (TNS V1-V3)`.

As SQL Developer is using JDBC, that is overriding both program and module with it's own value; and SQL*Plus is overriding the default module value.

So if the application using the session ID you're interested in has configured any of those values you should get a pretty good idea of what it is. And if it hasn't then you may still get clues about the kind of application (e.g. JDBC). The `osuser` might be useful too.

See [`SYS_CONTEXT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SYS_CONTEXT.html) and the [`DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.html) and [`DBMS_SESSION`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_SESSION.html) packages for more about how an application can set those values.